# How to disable the Keyboard Layouts Choosing screen in Gnome?

Tags: 17.10, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

On Ubuntu 17.10, When try to switch layouts by clicking Super + Space, I get the current window losing focus for a moment, which -usually- make the first letters I try to type missing.

The reason -as I think- is the popup screen appears with Layouts Choices, which get completely visible, if I continued holding the Super key after hitting the Space.

Example:
[image: The popup]

So, Is there a way to disable that popup ?

Thanks.

Comment: your apparent loss of focus may actually be a system halt as the new layout is applied. if this is the case then there is nothing to be done about it but wait a couple seconds.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to disable that feature, but there may be a workaround.

You can install `gnome-tweak-tool` and then search for and open Tweaks from the Activities overview. You'll find a GUI for setting an alternative shortcut for input source switching at *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout*.

AFAIK, that window does not pop up when using such an alternative shortcut.

Comment: Tried setting Ctrl + Shift as the switching shortcut, the popup not showing anymore, but still getting the focus lost for a moment the same as been happening with the popup !

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson and code2be, it seems this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1244090)

Comment: @code2be: I see. Maybe you type too fast. ;)

Comment: @RobertRiedl: Thanks for pointing at that bug report. It may be it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson : Switching to MATE might be an option, according to one user.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, Actually I do type a lot in two languages at the same time, mixed languages text, which make such issue very disturbing ! :), as I do lose lot of characters just after switching to different layout !

Comment: @RobertRiedl, I think it is the same issue, thanks for referencing to that bug !

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of more help