# How can I switch keyboard source quickly in Ubuntu GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

The keyboard shortcut for switching source is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. If I press it, this window dialog pops up:

[image: Screenshot of keyboard switcher dialog with en1, en2 and ar]

This is quite a slow process. You can press the keyboard shortcut multiple times until you have highlighted the keyboard layout that you need. However, once you have selected it, it seems that you must wait one or two whole seconds before you can type with that keyboard layout and the dialog fades out. Other operating systems let you change keyboard layouts instantaneously, is there a way to do this on Ubuntu?

To be clear, I quite like the window, the window popping up is not the problem. The problem is that it steals keyboard focus. How can I make it not steal keyboard focus? Or is there at least a way to close this window, say with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the Keyboard Layouts Choosing screen in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998077/how-to-disable-the-keyboard-layouts-choosing-screen-in-gnome)

Comment: See also [bug #1754702](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1754702).

Comment: is the same with the mouse, on the top panel (in your case, next to the Wifi logo)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to NOT show this window when changing language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972926/how-to-not-show-this-window-when-changing-language)

Comment: @pomsky Not a duplicate, as I'm fine with the window displaying, I just don't want it to steal keyboard focus.

Comment: Well, that's not how your question [originally was](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1048805/1). In that case you'll probably have to report a bug.

Comment: @pomsky The question never stated in the original version or the edited version that I wanted the window to not appear. I only stated that I wanted the whole process to be immediate.

Comment: The title went "*How can I switch keyboard source quickly in Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME Shell?*" and in the body, you just described how the super+space switching works with  a delay. So I reckon it's very natural to presume you were open to alternative suggestions to switch layout in a faster way (my answer to the proposed dupe has one). But nevermind, I guess nothing constructive is going to come out of this discussion any more, so I'll disengage. Thank you :) (I have retracted my close vote)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One blazing fast and radical way to achieve that is modeless and stateless input layout switching. It means, that instead of switching your layouts in cycle (e.g. for 3 languages: US → DE → JP → US → DE → …) you assign a unique combination for every input layout. E.g. <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> for US, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> for DE, and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> for JP). Then, every time you need a specific layout you just switch to it.

It's pretty hard to achieve in Ubuntu, as none of the methods that you could Google works properly.

- The `setxkbmap` doesn't play nice with the GNOME Shell.
- The `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current` is deprecated and doesn't work anymore
- The `gdbus call … org.gnome.Shell.Eval …` is also deprecated due to security implications.

So, I've made my own GNOME Shell Extension and I'm sharing it with the world: [Shyriiwook](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6691/shyriiwook/) (also available @ GitHub: [madhead/shyriiwook](https://github.com/madhead/shyriiwook)).

This is a very simple, minimalist extension. It doesn't have any GUI. After installing it, a new D-Bus interface would be exposed in your GNOME Shell session. You could query it for the current configuration or call a method to activate the desired layout:

```shell
$ gdbus introspect \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --only-properties

node /me/madhead/Shyriiwook {
  interface me.madhead.Shyriiwook {
    properties:
      readonly as availableLayouts = ['us', 'de', 'jp'];
      readonly s currentLayout = 'us';
  };
};

$ gdbus call \
    --session \
    --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /me/madhead/Shyriiwook \
    --method me.madhead.Shyriiwook.activate "de"
```

This is easily scriptable, and you can even put this command raw into a custom shortcut under the "Settings" → "Keyboard" → "Keyboard Shortcuts" → "View and Customise Shortcuts" → "Custom Shortcuts".

And, just like OP wanted, it happens immediately and doesn't show a popup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a script can be used to override this extremely annoying behavior. Take a look here:

[How to NOT show keyboard layout chooser popup when changing language in GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972926/how-to-not-show-keyboard-layout-chooser-popup-when-changing-language-in-gnome-3/1084210#1084210)