# Changing layout freezes my machine

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I use more than one language, and that's why I have to change layouts. But after doing it on my laptop, it freezes for a second. It's not a big issue and I can't live with it, but if it can be fixed, I'd like to.

I run the same Ubuntu 18.04 on both my PC and my laptop, and this issue only shows up with the second one (but that's not a surprise, because my PC is for sure way more powerful than my laptop).

I've also used 'Gnome Tweaks' to set layout changing to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but using default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> seems to make it freeze, too (even though it feels somewhat faster).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/998077/how-to-disable-the-keyboard-layouts-choosing-screen-in-gnome

Comment: See also [bug #1754702](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1754702).

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you managed to fix yours?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Gnome. For now it's impossible to say when if ever it's going to be fixed. However, you may be interested in either running Gnome on Wayland (this bug is not present there, but there are some other issues, depending on your workload you may be ok with it) or use another desktop environment, such as MATE, Cinnamon or KDE, which do not have this problem.